# How do you get a non-italic pound sign? (£)

Tags: italic

How do you get a non-italic pound sign? (£)

Comment: Which font family do you use?

Comment: This is available in Table 3: LaTeX2e Commands Defined to Work in Both Math and Text Mode (p 14) of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (discussed within the duplicate link).

Comment: @Werner I think it's completely wrong to close this as a dup of the general question, there are specific issues for \pounds in the cm fonts related to the fact that it is the `$` in the italic font. (not to mention the fact that it's not typically a math symbol at all)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Answer (score 17):

In the original cm fonts (OT1 encoding) £ was encoded as italic $ but in the
 8bit encoding (T1) it is not an issue:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\pounds\ and \textit{\pounds}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get an upright/non-italic £ with `T1` and `OT1`. I still think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Werner yes latex goes to some efforts to use the upright italic font in OT1 \pounds (but I half suspect the OP is using plain tex, otherwise the question wouldn't have arisen:-)

Comment: @David. Works with T1, but the PDF looks really bad. Like a scanned document.

Comment: @Nico. Not sure, I guess it's cm.

Comment: @Daniel: [This is the zoomed-in quality I get without loading `fontenc`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5PtE.png).

Comment: Makes me want to give up the whole thing and go back to stupid Word. Can't even post proper comments.

Comment: @Daniel If you are getting pixelated fonts you have a badly configured setup using bitmap fonts. But that would be unlikely to just affect \pounds? I t should be using scalable fonts so smooth outlines as in the images Werner and I posted

Comment: All right, I gave up and went back to stupid Words, too many problems with LaTeX. I installed the cmr font in Word, looks OK, but no accented letters such as ü and é. It changes to Cambria with those. Sigh.

Comment: @Daniel if you want a font similar to cm that works in other applications don't use cmr10 (the font encoding will not be understood) use the latin modern opentype font (you'll have a copy in your tex setup)

Comment: @David. Looks awesome but no Cyrillic.

Comment: @Daniel computer modern has no cyrillic either, oh perhaps you were using the cm unicode fonts Ok they are good alternative to latin modern

Comment: OK thanks David. I am using LM, with Garamond for Cyrillic. Looks OK. Cyrillic S is not absolutely identical to Latin C, but close enough.

Comment: \pounds just this works too

Answer (score 1):

Use `\pounds` (natively supported in LaTeX) or `\faGbp` from [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\pounds\ \verb|\pounds|

\faGbp\ \verb|\faGbp|

\end{document}
```